# Problem during DNA extraction from blood using automated magnetic beads extraction protocol

Tags: dna, dna-isolation

We've been using the Perkin Elmer Prepito D instrument + the Blood 250 associated kit for DNA isolation from blood for the last couple of years. It's been working well, however, lately the resulting extracts all show a null concentration. We've tried changing the kit and working with fresh blood with no results. We've also observed that the DNA seems to stay in the disposable deep wells plate bonded to the magnetic beads and it does not get transferred to the final tubes.

Does anyone have experience working with the Prepito instrument or have experienced a similar problem with any magnetic beads DNA isolation protocols ? Does anyone have any suggestion to what might be causing this problem or how we may solve it ?[image: Photo of the disposable Deepwells plate]

Comment: Have you tried contacting the customer service about the issue?

Comment: I agree with @Chris, but there a few things to test first - ensure that the kit is prepared correctly using fresh reagents - don't let a newbie do it!